# Selects dinâmicos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar selects dinâmicos em uma página, idêntico ao cadastro de anúncios do mercado livre.

Na verdade, estou tentando criar uma integração exatamente com a rotina deles. Estou tendo dificuldades com as categorias. Conforme o tipo da categoria pai, é necessário abrir um novo select com as categorias filho e assim por diante. Não tem como saber a quantidade de itens e nem a hierarquia.

Fiz o select da categoria principal, dessa forma:

```
<div id="categoria">
<label>Categoria</label>
<select id="cmbCategoria" class="sub">
    <option>Carregar Categoria</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Carregar Categoria" id="btnCategoria" class="botao"/>
</div>
```

Pelo que pesquisei, para incluir um select seria dessa forma:

```
$("#categoria" ).append("<select class='sub' id="+id+"><option value>Subcategoria</option></select>");
```

Teria alguma maneira mais fácil? Consigo pegar o id do select dinâmico?

Comment: A ideia parece certa, mas de onde vc vai puxar esses dados? Via Ajax?

Comment: O ideal seria você ja deixar esses dados salvos em uma variável no JavaScript, assim economizaria recursos do seu servidor, e exibiria no HTML de acordo com o que o usuário fosse selecionando.

Answer (score 0):

Se este `<select>` está sendo montado dinamicamente e você deseja adicionar mais itens "dinamicamente", deves buscar o elemento dinamicamente:

```js
let categorias = [
   {
      id: 001,
      value: 'imoveis'
   },
   {
      id: 002,
      value: 'carros'
   },
   {
      id: 003,
      value: 'celulares'
   },
   {
      id: 004,
      value: 'computadores'
   }
]

// primeira iteração (adicionar categoria(s))
categorias.forEach(item => {
    $('#select').append(`<optgroup id="${item.id}" label="${item.value}"></optgroup>`)
})

// segunda iteração (adicionar itens a elementos dinamicos)
categorias.forEach(item => {
    $('#'+item.id).append(`
        <option>item 001</option>
        <option>item 002</option>
        <option>item 003</option>
    `)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="select"></select>
```

Se você conhece a estrutura dos dados deves simplesmente mapeá-la e iterar. Estes dados podem vir de um `JSON` ai basta fazer o parse (`JSON.parse()`) se for uma matriz já disponível no front-end (javascript) basta percorre-lá.

Este exemplo é simples e distribui em grupos, mesmo que sua solução utilize um select "customizado" a lógica deve ser a mesma.